# grep files against a list only containing numbers

Tags: bash, grep

I have several files (~70000) that have numbers in the name, a couple of examples would be `991000_Metatissue.qsub.file` `828000_Metatissue.qsub.file`, and then I have another file (`files_failed.txt`) with a bunch of numbers that I would use to grep. This list looks like this:

```
 4578000
 458000
 4582000
 527000
 5288000
 5733000
 653000
 6548000
 6663000
```

I have tried with: `ls -1 *.qsub.file | grep -F -f files_failed.txt -` and even doing this:

```
  ls -1 *.qsub.file > files_to_submit.txt
  grep -F -f files_failed.txt files_to_submit.txt
```

But always got all the `qsub.files`...

Comment: Isn't there an empty line somewhere in the file? (Most probably at the very end).

Comment: Try also with the `-w` flag for grep, so that `10` doesn't match in `9910999`.

Comment: @choroba, I have removed the empty lines but still don't get the exact match for example the number `69000` is matched in `1069000_Metatissue.qsub.file` and in `69000_Metatissue.qsub.file`. If I add `-w` the grep command doesn't return anything

Comment: Following the same approach, you could do `ls -1 ./*qsub.file`, then you can look for `./12345_`. Other than that you can use regex.

Comment: Please, run `file files_failed.txt files_to_submit.txt` and post its output.

Comment: this is the output of the command @Jdamian: `files_failed.txt:    ASCII text
files_to_submit.txt: ASCII text`

Comment: @RobertSeaman your approach works but I am still curious if I can get an exact match when the "grepping" involves numbers, thanks

Comment: `sed -i 's/[[:space:]]*//g;s/^/^/;s/$/_/' files_failed.txt` , `grep -f files_failed.txt files_to_submit.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `find` and you need to modify your "patterns".  Here is one way that should work:

```
# List all files ending in "qsub.file"
find . -name '*.qsub.file' |

# Add ./ and _ to each number to make the match exact
grep -F -f <(sed -e 's:^:./:' -e 's/$/_/' files_failed.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep -f` isn't well composed (see [GNU bug 16305](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?16305)), so I recommend using awk instead:

```
find . -name '*_*.qsub.file' |awk -F_ '
  NR == FNR { failed[$NR] = 1; next }
  $1 in failed
' files_failed.txt /dev/stdin
```

This uses `find` to locate the files in question, piping them into awk.  Before awk processes that, it reads `files_failed.txt` and stores the values into an associated array (aka dictionary or hash) when the line number (`NR`, number of records so far) equals the line number of the current file (`FNR`), meaning it's the first file read.  If the first column (the number of the file since we delimited by `_`) is in that array, it was a failure.  AWK's default action on a stanza is to print it, so you will get a list of those failed files.

Note the lack of regular expressions!  On a big directory, **this is much faster than `grep -F -f …`**, which itself is much faster than `grep -f …`, even assuming the aforementioned bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

70000 files is too much for a ls, you should use find instead.

And I prefer invert the logic, list just what a want instead of list all and then filter.

Something like

```
while read line; do find -iname $line_Metatissue.qsub.file; done < files_failed.txt
```

If you need the exit in another file?

```
while read line; do find -iname $line_Metatissue.qsub.file; done < files_failed.txt >> files_to_submit.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script:-

```
 ls -1 *.qsub.file > filelist.txt
 while read pattern
 do
     filefound=$(grep $pattern  filelist.txt)
     if [ "$filefound" != "" ]; then
         echo "File Found : $filefound"
     fi 
 done < files_failed.txt
```

Second option:-

```
  while read pattern
  do
      find . -name "$pattern*.qsub.file" >> filefound.txt       
  done < files_failed.txt
```

All your files will be stored in file `filefound.txt`